# Wrap query with parallel using Querydsl

Tags: oracle, hibernate, querydsl

I’m using Oracle and QueryDsl version 5.0.0 .
I have this oracle sql query:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(2)*/ *
FROM (
WITH temp AS (
SELECT name1, name2 FROM names
--Dynamic filters are added here from client)
SELECT name1 AS name FROM temp
UNION ALL (SELECT name2 AS name FROM temp)
);
```

Filter for example - where name1 is John or Adam:

```
[…]
WITH temp AS (
SELECT name1, name2
FROM names
WHERE name1 IN (‘John’, ‘Adam’))
[…]
```

My code:

> Note that `this.getConditions(Request request)` return BooleanBuilder which contains the filters that the client sent.

```java
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private final QNames namesTable = QNames.names;
private final QNames withTable = new Qnames("with");

public List<String> getNames(Request request) throw Exception {
    Connection conn = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

    OracleQuery<Names> withQuery = new OracleQuery<Names>(conn)
        .select(Projections.constructor(
            Names.class,
            this.namesTable.name1.as(this.withTable.name1),
            this.names.name2.as(this.withTable.name2))
        )
        .from(this.names)
        .where(this.getConditions(request));

    OracleQuery<String> name1Query = new OracleQuery<String>(conn)
        .select(this.withTable.name1.as("name"))
        .from(this.withTable);

    OracleQuery<String> name2Query = new OracleQuery<String>(conn)
        .select(this.withTable.name2.as(“name”))
        .from(this.withTable);

    OracleQuery<String> fullQuery = new OracleQuery<String>(conn)
        .with(this.withTable, withQuery);

    fullQuery.unionAll(name1Query, name2Query);

    return fullQuery.fetch();
}
```

I don’t know how to add parallel to this code.

I’ve tried to add this code instead of the return line:

```java
OracleQuery<String> parallelFullQuery = new OracleQuery<String>(conn)
.select(fullQuery)
.addFlag(QueryFlag.Position.START, "select /*+ parallel(2)*/ * from (")
.addFlag(QueryFlag.Position.END, ")")
.from(fullQuery);

return parallelFullQuery.fetch();
```

But it override the WITH clause.

Any Ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to run `alter session force parallel query parallel 2` before the query, and then run `alter session enable parallel query` after the query? (Although that would be more complicated than a single SQL statement because of multiple calls, and you'd probably have to catch exceptions to make sure parallelism is always reset, and altering the session might also cause issues with session pooling.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a custom Hibernate `Dialect` by providing a query comment. You can set the comment via a JPA query hint `org.hibernate.comment`. Then in the `Dialect` you can apply that comment by implementing `addSqlHintOrComment`